# Proving differentiability of simple polynomial map

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials

I'm trying to show the differentiability of the following simple polynomial map $\phi$ $$\phi : P \mapsto P^3, P \in \mathbb{R}_q[X]$$. I go by the definition of differentiability, i.e. I search for a linear continuous mapping $d\phi_P : \mathbb{R}_q[X] \to \mathbb{R}_{3q}[X]$ such that $\phi(P+h) - \phi(P) = d\phi_P(h) + o(h)$.

So, I calculate $\phi(P+h), h \in \mathbb{R}_q[X]$ and I obtain $$\phi(P+h) - \phi(P) = 3P^2h+3Ph^2+h^3$$ aaaand I'm stuck. I mean, $h^3$ is from $\mathbb{R}_q[X]$ to $\mathbb{R}_{3q}[X]$ but it's not linear. And even if it were linear and continuous, I wouldn't be able to show that $3P^2h+3Ph^2 = o(h)$.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3P^2\cdot h$ is the linear part, $3Ph^2 + h^3$ is $o(h)$. Hence, 
$$
\phi'(P) h = 3P^2 \cdot h.
$$

Comment: Oups, I got tricked into thinking that the linear part MUST be of degree $3q$ (yeah, but then how would it be linear..?) :( Instead it suffices to be in $\mathbb{R}_{3q}[X]$. Can you please explain how you show that $3Ph^2+h^3$ is $o(h)$? The norm here is $\lVert P \rVert = \sup_{t \in [0, 1]} | P(t)|$. Do we just brutally bound $3Ph^2+h^3$ by $\lVert h \rVert (3Ph^2+h^3)$ ?

Comment: Any bound of the type $\|3Ph2+h3\|\le c\|h\|^2$ will do the trick.